# How to make model trim for animation optimization

Tags: modeling, animation, scripting, modifiers, rigging

When I saw Tintin animation movie behind scenes, I see the models are reduced its poly like the image given below. I want to know what is this process technically called and how can we make the models like this? Is there any plugins to create this in blender or Maya?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]